# Create an array filled with separate hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I'm trying to create an array in which every entry should be a separate, identical hash entry in the beginning.

```
iTabSize = 500 #protein max lenght
arrTable = Array.new(iTabSize) 
hshTable = {"-"=>0,"B"=>0,"Z"=>0,"I"=>0,"M"=>0,"T"=>0,"N"=>0,"K"=>0,"S"=>0,"R"=>0,"V"=>0,"A"=>0,"D"=>0,"E"=>0,"G"=>0,"F"=>0,"L"=>0,"Y"=>0,"X"=>0,"C"=>0,"W"=>0,"P"=>0,"H"=>0,"Q"=>0}
0.upto(iTabSize){|x| arrTable[x]= hshTable}
```

The problem is if I change the hash in one entry of the array, the hash gets updated for all other entries :/

```
arrTable[x][strSeq[x]] = arrTable[x][strSeq[x]] + 1
```

strSeq is a sequence containing letters from the hash.
The result is that each x of arrTable contains exactly the same values?

Am I doing something wrong when creating the array with hashes?

I tried with

```
arrTable = Array.new {Hash.new}
arrTable[x] = Array.new
```

but it doesn't change a thing!
Tnx!

Comment: spickermann gave a good answer.  The problem is that `arrTable[x] = hshTable` is ensuring every array entry is pointing to the same object (the hash `hshTable`).  What you want is for every entry to have a new object which is a copy of the original hash.  `hshTable.clone` will give you a new (cloned) object from the hash table.

Comment: It's not relevant to your question, but an easy way to generate `hshTable` is `hshTable["-", *?A..?Z].product([0]).to_h`, assuming  you don't care about the order of keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
max_protein = 500
hash_table  = {"-"=>0,"B"=>0,"Z"=>0,"I"=>0,"M"=>0,"T"=>0,"N"=>0,"K"=>0,"S"=>0,"R"=>0,"V"=>0,"A"=>0,"D"=>0,"E"=>0,"G"=>0,"F"=>0,"L"=>0,"Y"=>0,"X"=>0,"C"=>0,"W"=>0,"P"=>0,"H"=>0,"Q"=>0}

array_table = Array.new(max_protein) { hash_table.clone }
```